# How to add MongoDB to Lift WebApp in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, scala, mongodb, lift

I can't add MongoDb to my Lift WebApp. I have added the maven dependency i.e.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.liftweb</groupId>
  <artifactId>lift-mongodb-record_2.9.1</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

to my pom.xml file, but I still get `not found: object mongodb` when I try `import mongodb._`

Here is the code where I get the error (taken from https://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Mongo_Configuration)

```
import net.liftweb._
import mongodb._ // <- Here is the problem
import util.Props
import com.mongodb.{ Mongo, ServerAddress }

object MongoConfig {
  def init: Unit = {
    val srvr = new ServerAddress(
      Props.get("mongo.host", "127.0.0.1"),
      Props.getInt("mongo.port", 27017))
    MongoDB.defineDb(DefaultMongoIdentifier, new Mongo(srvr), "myapp")
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm using eclipse and the project was created using maven archetype lift-archetype-basic_2.9.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with Eclipse and its plugins - can't find the appropriate jars or something.

I tried by not using IDE and it works. It also works with Intellij IDEA CE 11.1. so I'll be using that for development.

Answer (score 1):

You should post the source and the exact error message when asking for help. AFAIK there is no mongodb package or object...

Anyway, here is an example code which works:

```
import net.liftweb.mongodb.record.{ MongoId, MongoRecord, MongoMetaRecord }
import net.liftweb.record.field.StringField
import net.liftweb.mongodb.record.field.MongoMapField

object Device extends Device with MongoMetaRecord[Device]

class Device private () extends MongoRecord[Device] with MongoId[Device] {
  def meta = Device

  type idType = _id.MyType

  object serial extends StringField(this, "")
  object name extends StringField(this, "")
  object deviceInfo extends MongoMapField[Device, Any](this)
}
```

Your dependency looks good.

Comment: The exact error message is just that "not found: object mongodb". I posted the code where I get that message. Anyway I can't see the jar downloaded in my Maven Dependencies and added to the build path, so that's why I think something is wrong with the dependency configuration.

Comment: I managed to make this work without using eclipse. I have tested with your code and it works. It seems that this is eclipse's problem...

Answer (score 0):

You can add it in your build.sbt file :

```
libraryDependencies ++= {
    val liftVersion = "2.4"
    Seq(
        [...]
        "net.liftweb" %% "lift-mongodb" % "2.4",
        "net.liftweb" %% "lift-mongodb-record" % "2.4",
        "com.foursquare" %% "rogue" % "1.0.29" withSources(),
        [...]
    )}
```